# how to call a method by notification with out any click of user on notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, unnotificationrequest

I want to call my method on particular time (like 5:00 pm , 6:00 pm etc). 
In my app user enter a time suppose he enters 6:00 pm and I am scheduling internally local notification at 5:00 pm. and at 5:00 pm my notification occurs but I want that user don't know about that notification that will be a silent notification and once it will occur I need to call a method internally and show result to user when he opens the application.

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Simple answer; you can't. There is no way to schedule app execution at a particular time on iOS. You could send a silent push notification from a server but there is no guarantee that it will be delivered at that time due to network connectivity/device switched off etc.

Comment: If you want to call a method by notification then you have to run a background process in the app. But this feature is not supported by apple. So it is not possible to trigger a method from background without user interaction.

Comment: Thanks for reply Paulw and Tan, but any other solution..